# Java RMI Pass by reference

Tags: java, rmi

I want to know if it is possible to pass an object by reference with java RMI.

To be more specific I want to do something like this

Client end:

> server.getSomeitem(someitemID).getSomeOtherItem(otherItemId).setItemValue(String someValue);

Where on the server end the `getsomeitem` object returns an object with the index that is sent in, then off of that object call `getsomeotheritem` from that index then call `setItemValue` on that object.

I want this to affect that values on the server side and not just sent a copy of the objects to the client.

Is this possible?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087756/rmi-pass-by-value-or-by-reference

Comment: I have tried that however I still seem to be getting issues

Comment: Getting the first item works fine however anything after that gets a null

Comment: Copying a comment from EJP here (I think it is correct): "RMI passes remote references by value, just like the JVM does with parameters. It passes non-remote parameters by value. By-reference doesn't come into it anywhere." (see comments on [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3087795/3080094) from the previously mentioned question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the object concerned is an exported remote object its (remote) reference will be passed. Otherwise the entire object is passed by value copy via Serialization.

Comment: Does each object need to be exported separately?. Say the first one it gets is a different class than the second one it gets. I guess I am a bit confused about which objects need exported and how to do that. I have the first object where the first method is called exported and from that I am getting the others currently.

Comment: I suggest you just stop, calm down, and read my answer again.